# Using Enums from Super Class in Child Class

Tags: java, enums

My base class declares an enum, and declares a field of that enum type.

```
public abstract class Format {

    ...

    /**
     * compression types
     */
    public static enum CompressionType {
        /**
         * no compression
         */
        NO_COMPRESSION,
        /**
         * RLE8 compression
         */
        RLE_8,
        /**
         * RLE4 compression
         */
        RLE_4
    }

    /**
     * compression type of the image
     */
    public CompressionType compressionType;
    ...
```

And I want a child class of Format to set a value to that field.

```
public class Bitmap extends Format {
        ...
        // get compression type
        String cType = data[offset+30];
        if(cType.equals("00"))
            // this is what I want to do
            super.compressionType = NO_COMPRESSION;
        ...
```

Is there a way to do this? I've tried using super.NO_COMPRESSION, but that doesn't work, and I've tried to most intuitive thing to do, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be like this:

```
this.compressionType = Format.CompressionType.NO_COMPRESSION
```

Or

```
this.compressionType = CompressionType.NO_COMPRESSION
```

---

If you do a `static` import of `Format.CompressionType.NO_COMPRESSION`, you can even do:

```
this.compressionType = NO_COMPRESSION
```

Answer (score 3):

Qualify your enum with the enum name. So use

```
CompressionType.NO_COMPRESSION
```

or

```
Format.CompressionType.NO_COMPRESSION
```

if not in the child class.

Comment: @Hovercraft_Full_Of_Eels This is it! Thank you! I feel dumb now. haha